# gaslimit for a block and other questions related to gas model

Tags: ethereum

i know what is a gas, gaslimit and gasprice, but still have confusion even after searching and reading through the Internet.

- There is a gaslimit per block, but why many blocks did not reach it? in other words, can a miner send a block to the network without reaching the gaslimit for the block?
- Assume the block gaslimit is 4 million and i sent a transaction with 4 million gaslimit. But when the miner executed it (used gas was 1 million). Can the miner add extra transactions to the block to fill the remaining 3 million or not. In another way, does a transaction with a big gaslimit (but uses a fraction of that gas) affects the miner of adding more transactions to the block?
- Each Opcode coast some value of gas. How Ethereum measure the cost of each EVM opcode? (any reference for explanation?).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1** The block gas limit is an upper bound on the total cost of transactions that can be included in a block. Yes, the miner can and should send a solved block to the network, even if the gas cost is 0. Blocks are meant to arrive at a steady pace in any case. So "nothing happened during this period" is a valid solution.

**Q2a** The gas cost of a transaction is the total cost of executing the transaction. Not subject to guesswork. If the actual cost exceeds the supplied gas then the transaction fails with an out-of-gas exception. If there is surplus gas, it's returned to the sender.

**Q2b** Yes, a miner can and should include multiple transactions in a block. **A block is a well-ordered set of transactions that were accepted by the network.** It's a unit of disambiguation that clearly defines the accepted order of events. Have a look here for exact meaning of this: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13887/is-consensus-necessary-for-ethereum

**Q3** I can't say for sure (possibly someone can confirm) that this is an up-to-date list: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1m89CVujrQe5LAFJ8-YAUCcNK950dUzMQPMJBxRtGCqs/edit#gid=0

Comment: Many thanks Rob!. for Q1: you mean miners every 15 sec for example will generate a block even though there is no transaction in it. This is why i see mined block with 0 gas used in etherscan. For Q2 to clarify my point, can a block have 6 million of total gas limit, but the used gas is 4 million, assuming each block is limited by 4 million? some users just double the amount of gas in transactions to avoid out of gas issue. Thanks again

Comment: Q1: Yes. Blocks predictably arrive at consistent average rate. Q2: I feel like I'm trying to unconfuse something. The sum of the gas used by all the transactions in a block can't exceed the block gas limit. Transactions may be deferred to the next block at the miner's discretion, e.g., they don't "fit". To ensure a transaction is funded, one can attach the maximum amount of gas. "burned" != "supplied". Supplied may be much higher. I can supply 4MM gas for a txn expected to burn 80,000. I get the leftover gas back in most cases. It's like arriving at your destination with leftover fuel. Helps?

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob. I understand everything now!